# How to make a `unittest.mock._patch` instance subscriptable and iterable

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest, monkeypatching

I have a class which works approximately like this:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, iterable: List[...]):
        self.iterable = iterable

    def __getitem__(self, i: int):
        return self.iterable[i]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.iterable)
```

So the indexing and iteration behavior operates on an attribute `iterable` (which is a list) without needing to explicitly reference that attribute. For example:

```
>>> foo = Foo(iterable=['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> foo[-1]
'c'
>>> for x in foo:
...    print(x)
...
a
b
c
```

My current approach to testing this class uses `unittest.mock.patch` like this:

```
def test_foo():
    mock_foo = patch('my_module.Foo', autospec=True)
    mock_foo.iterable = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    mock_foo.__getitem__ = lambda self, i: self.iterable[i]
    mock_foo.__iter__ = lambda self: iter(self.iterable)
```

So I simply create the patch, then define the attributes and dunders necessary to replicate the behavior of the target class.

However, when I attempt to index into or iterate over the patch, it doesn't work:

```
>>> mock_foo[-1]
TypeError: '_patch' object is not subscriptable
>>> list(mock_project_export_set)
TypeError: '_patch' object is not iterable
```

This is unexpected and confusing, because when I invoke the dunders directly, everything works as desired:

```
>>> mock_foo.__getitem__(mock_foo, -1)
'c'
>>> list(mock_foo.__iter__(mock_foo))
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Why the inconsistency? How can I replicate the behavior of my class in the test?

I'm not super experienced with patching/mocking, so if there's an altogether superior and simpler way, I'd love to know.

Python 3.11.3
My testing framework is `pytest`.

Comment: It looks like you are testing the mock instead of the class. You never patch what you want to test.

Comment: @KlausD. Not quite. I am testing a separate function which takes an instance of `Foo` as an argument. `Foo` is a complex class, so I am mocking the instance such that if the test fails, I know the bug stems from that function and not from `Foo`. But to do this, at a minimum, the mock must replicate `Foo`'s `__iter__` behavior, because the function being tested relies on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, you testing the `patch` instead of the `MagicMock`

from the documentation of [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock)

```py
from unittest.mock import patch


def test_foo():
    patcher = patch('my_module.foo.Foo', autospec=True) # depending on your structure
    mock_foo_class = patcher.start()
    mock_foo_class.iterable = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    mock_foo_class.__getitem__ = lambda self, i: self.iterable[i]
    mock_foo_class.__iter__ = lambda self: iter(self.iterable)
```

An alternative approach would be using the patch as a decorator, depending on what u trying to accomplish:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch


@patch('my_module.foo.Foo') # depending on your structure
def test_foo(mock_foo):
    mock_foo.iterable = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    mock_foo.__getitem__ = lambda self, i: self.iterable[i]
    mock_foo.__iter__ = lambda self: iter(self.iterable)
    assert mock_foo[-1] == 'c'
    assert list(mock_foo) == mock_foo.iterable
```